# Haskell - How to create a function which will repeat a line of code n times

Tags: loops, haskell, recursion, repeat

Firstly, I would like to explain that this problem is mainly due to my difficulty in understanding how to avoid the requirement for a 'for' loop in functional programming in general.

I know that this is a very common problem which newbies to functional programming have, and I have spent hours trawling through posts similar to this. However I still have not yet found a solution to my particular problem.

**I have the following problem:**

I am using a simple 2d graphics window with pre made Haskell commands to control a cursor which will trace a line on the screen wherever the cursor moves.

I am attempting to create a function which will cause the cursor to trace a regular polygon with n sides.

This involves repeating the following line of code n times:

```
Fd 1 :> Rt (360/(fromIntegral n))
```

This code says: "move forward (forward is relative to the current *direction* of the cursor) by 1 unit" and then: "turn the cursor clockwise by 360/n degrees".

Obviously I now need to create a function which can repeat the above line of code n times to create the regular polygon.

I have tried several approaches to solve the problem recursively however the best I can currently manage is the following:

```
rep :: (Eq a, Integral a) => a -> Command -> Command
rep 1 action = action
rep n action = rep (n-1) action
```

As it is, this code compiles fine and will ultimately recurse all the way back to n=1 where it will perform the action once (the action will be the first line of code)

I instinctively want to get the last line of that code to simultaneously, perform the action *and* call itself with n-1 and action as parameters. But I don't know if this is possible or if it is even the best way of achieving what I want to accomplish.

Any insight anyone can give me on this problem would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're the 2nd person from the same university course I'm going to answer to - [here's the first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736975/how-to-define-an-n-sided-polygon-function-in-haskell/33738198#33738198). Or wait, it's an exact duplicate. If you think there's something you don't know that isn't answered there, please post a comment.

Comment: Wow, my bad, thanks anyway.